# What is a galaxy seed and setup to get the Immortal Bard achievement?

Tags: achievements, endless-space

For the immortal bard achievement you need to hire two specific heroes:

> Tethys and Karta

Can you give a Galaxy seed and setup details where achieving this is possible?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
seed: 184133953
Spiral-8,medium 2 empires,normal age
average system balancing,Medium galaxy density
Normal,Few
Average,Average
Normal,Normal
Normal
Started with Karta Vauclas
On turn 493 I finally got Tephys
```

[Taken from this Steam Community Post](http://steamcommunity.com/app/208140/discussions/0/846958223169029624/?l=norwegian).

If you want to speed things up however, the same post also suggests doing an edit to the Hero.xml files found in either "\Steam\steamapps\common\Endless Space\Public\Simulation" or "\Steam\steamapps\common\Endless Space\Public_xp1\Simulation", depending on if you have the original game or the expansion. This allows you to remove all heroes except those two you need. Remember to take a backup of "Hero.xml" first if you want to revert your changes.

Also, any mods you have activated will disable you getting this achievement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sadly the seed does not seem to work.

Comment: Did you try the other suggestion?